# How to detect clickable link in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, url

I am getting a response in a list from backend and putting error codes to a table as in picture
[image]

This explanation string has a URL in it as you see www.google... I want to make it clickable but I cannot.

When I try to replace the link with regex with following codes (my model object for the table item is *response: errorArray.slice(1, errorArray.length)*);

```
const urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
        const errorArray = errorResponse.error.toString()
          .replace(/\[/g, "")
          .replace(/]/g, "")
          .replace(urlRegex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank' ></a>")
          .replace(/\.,/g, ".")
this.allUploadedPinsFiles.push({uploadDate: uploaded, fileName: file.name,
          status: status, responseHeader: errorArray[0], response: errorArray.slice(1, errorArray.length)});
```

It becomes 
[image]

It is replacing item in the error array but in UI it still shows as a text. How can I make it that it can understand the link in a text and make it clickable?

and here is the html code for that list:

```
<div *ngIf="upload.response.length > 0">
          <ul class="list-item">
            <li *ngFor="let singleResponce of upload.response">{{singleResponce}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hope https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `innerHtml`

```
 <li *ngFor="let singleResponce of upload.response">
     <span [innerHtml]="singleResponce"
 </li>
```

Comment: The solution provided by @Ininiv is much better as it [protects](https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext) you from XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize the data and pass to the html

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<a href='www.google.com' target='_blank'>My Link</a>)
```

Try this

[Working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbykf9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: but the text is in an array, I need to pick it up first. How can I pick it with regex and only show the link as clickable?